# TFS 2010 - We have code branches. What is the best way to tell devs which branch to code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, branching-and-merging, tfs-workitem

What's the best way in your experience to designate where work items should be coded?  Do you use a particular field?  We currently use a custom "Version to Fix" field in our WIT, but it doesn't relate directly to Dev or the Main line code branches.  We end up communicating which Versions (v6.1, v6.2, etc) relate to which branches, but there is still a "mapping" that needs to be done.  This really only works for a "Hot Fix" in a released version because the branch is named the same as the "Version to Fix".  How are work items designated so that is easy for developers to know where to code and provides the least amount of maintenance?

Updated: Just to clarify a bit ... we have Dev, Main, and Release (one for each release) branches.  We do 90% of our development in Dev.  Once an iteration has ended we reverse integrate Dev to Main, however we don't release it at that point.  Testing is done on Main for a while and select bugs could be fixed on Main.  This all goes on while the next Iteration (new stories) moves on in Dev.  Once things look good on Main we'll branch to a new version (new Release branch) and development on Main will end until the next iteration starts and we again Reverse Integrate to Main from Dev.  Of course we forward integrate Main to Dev once things are fixed on Main.  At any point we may have a bug that we want fixed on Dev, Main, or on a Released version.  Where we have bug fixes going on in Main, Dev, and Release we are confusing some developers.  We tell them the "version" but they have to know what future or current version links back to what Branch.  That's where I'm trying to find the best practice with the Task work item.

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple versions (changesets) within a branch, but the proliferation of branches is not a good idea.

A simple (but powerful) branching strategy is to create a main brach, then create 2 children: 1) Dev, 2) QA   Now the question is a non-question.  Developers do their work in the Dev branch.  When they're ready they reverse integrate changes to main.  Then changes are forward integrated to QA.  If the build passes QA, then it can be rolled to production.

Some organizations will employ special branching practices like creating a branch for a new Major version or even a branch for a special feature.   These follow the same process of reverse integration into main (and subsequent forward integration dev branches when appropriate).

Builds can be linked to changesets.   If a particular build has a bug, the developers look up the changeset number, pull it down from version control, check the work in associating it with appropriate work items for the Bug, and rebuild it.  That new "bug fix" version now has a unique build id and changeset id associated with it.

Comment: While it may not be a "good idea" to have a proliferation of branches, the "Feature Branch" system is a perfectly legitimate way of working and there are many SW shops that use this system.

Among other advantages, a major advantage is the ability to develop different features in parallel without having delays in one feature hold up the release of other features. Once a feature is ready, it is merged into the Main branch and deployed.

Now given that, when an R&D manager wishes to define a new work item, he will want to indicate in which branch the item is to be implemented. How???

Answer (score 0):

That's really going to depend on your shop; our environment works on an iterative build, so the bug fixes always go into the most recent branch (named via date stamp - IE Branch_05252011 or so).

If you have some other kind of versioning / branching strategy, the best option would be to place the desired fix branch in the title:

```
V6.2 - Fix the ItExplodedException occuring in SomeClass
```

Alternatively, I believe TFS can also even offer a specialized drop down that you can populate when creating the work item with custom content. You could then populate that with the branch to target.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very effective solution: Set up a check-in policy using TFS Power Tools, and associate a Custom Path policy with a Work Item Query policy, so that all checkins for a branch will require association with a work item that falls into a branch-specific query.  That way if the checkin does not have a work item that matches the branch, it will not be allowed.  The query can be defined using whatever criteria you need, and the queries themselves can be updates and reassigned to different branches as needed.

One caveat, however: the queries themselves are evaluated at client-side, so as an administrator you can update the query to block or allow certain items into a branch, but the developers will need to refresh Team Explorer to update their query, otherwise it can allow unauthorized items in, or it can block items that are authorized.  One solution I am looking into for this issue is to add a custom check-in policy that will always be satisfied but in the meantime will cause the VS IDE to refresh Team Explorer.  I have asked MS to add this directly to their TFS Power Tools Work Item Query checkin policy but they have not responded.